# How to enable miredo UPnP-Enabled Symmetric NAT Extension

Tags: linux, nat, upnp, teredo

I have linux mint and miredo installed on both machines.
Both machines are behind symmetric NAT. Routers have UPnP enabled.

Does miredo support upnp routers?
How to enable UPnP-Enabled Symmetric NAT Extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that miredo don't support UPnP. Check the [todo](http://git.remlab.net/gitweb/?p=miredo.git;a=blob;f=TODO;h=675e8e2d262dec1db4a1a9df2261e77ed8a56f75;hb=HEAD) list.

```
   1 ToDo list:
   2 ===========
   3 
   4 This task list is only indicative; in particular priorities are typically
   5 not quite respected and often modified. It might not be fully comprehensive.
   6 If you have an idea, please submit it to the miredo-devel mailing list.
   7 
   8 (!) must be done before next release
   9 (*) must be done before stable release
  10 ( ) should probably be done someday if one finds time and interest
  11 (?) should be evaluated for usefulness and/or feasibility first
  12 (H) should be done, but a capable volunteer is required
  13 
  14 Important features & fixes:
  15 ----------------------------
  16 (*) do something in case of DoS against the peers list
  17 ( ) fixed TODOs and FIXMEs in source code
  18 
  19 Not so important features:
  20 ---------------------------
  21 (H) other localizations
  22 ( ) support for UPnP IGD to open an UDP port on supporting NATs
  23 ( ) support for (Apple) NAT-PMP
  24 (?) “automatic sunset” / “exit strategy”
```